# Solving for an matrix containing complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

$$Ax = 0$$

$$A x= \begin{bmatrix}-6 -2i & 5\\0& 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

Simple question, but how do I solve for $x_1$ and $x_2$?

One potential answer is:

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}-1+2i\\-2+2i\end{bmatrix}$$

I'm not sure how to get a result like this with complex numbers though. Can I get a detailed explanation on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x_1=-6+2i$

$$(-6-2i)(-6+2i)+5x_2=0$$

$$36-(2i)^2+5x_2=0$$

$$40+5x_2=0$$

$$x_2=-8$$

Comment: How would it be possible to get $x1$ and $x2$ in the form $a+bi$?

Comment: what do you mean? isn't $x_1=-6+2i$ and $x_2=-10 + 0i$ in that form?

Comment: If I substitute in the values $-6 + 2i$ and $-10$ into $x1$ and $x2$, I get the matrix $<-10, 0>$, but it should be $<0, 0>$

Comment: Hi, I made a mistake earlier.